# cant send file through socket C

Tags: c, windows, sockets

it works only when i do it with my own Computer , but when i use another Computer the file recieved is a mess and the size is always another.

Server:

```
while (1) {
        ZeroMemory(r_buf, MAX_BUFF_RECV - 1);
        bytesReceived = recv(sock, r_buf, FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE, 0);

        if (bytesReceived < 0) {
            // ERROR
            puts("[!] recv failed");
            return;
        }
        else if (bytesReceived < FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE) {
            // LAST CHUNCK
            if (WriteFile(out, r_buf, bytesReceived, &n, NULL) == FALSE) {
                printf("WriteFile() error %d\n", GetLastError());
            }
            break;
        }
        else {
            if (WriteFile(out, r_buf, bytesReceived, &n, NULL) == FALSE) {
                printf("WriteFile() error %d\n", GetLastError());
            }
        }
    }
```

Client:

```
while (1)
    {
        ZeroMemory(buff, FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE);
        nread = fread(buff, 1, FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE, f);

        if (nread != FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE) {
            send(s, buff, nread, 0);
            break;
        }
        else {
            send(s, buff, nread, 0);
        }
    }
```

im for hours on it , pls tell me whats wrong

Comment: Please read the Stackoverflow help pages on how to post a good question. In particular please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). But for starters, is `MAX_BUFF_RECV` larger than `FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE`? If it isn't then you'll get memory corruption in the receiver. But we can't tell because you haven't shown that. Hence why an MCVE is important.

Comment: The main error is most likely your assumption that data comes in the same size blocks as you send it. This is not true. You may receive whatever size packets and you cannot determine based on them that the transfer has finished.

Comment: Alan Au: MAX_BUFF_RECV is the size of r_buf, so FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE is smaller , sure.

Comment: Sami Kuhmonen: so you wanna tell me that fread(buff, 1, FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE, f); and then send(s, buff, nread, 0);
wont always send FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE sized payloads?

Comment: thx for the hint ill check that....

Comment: no thats not the Problem

Answer (score 1):

In connection-oriented transports, like TCP, `send()` and `recv()` are not 1-to-1.  There is no guarantee that what you `send()` will be transmitted in a single data packet, or that `recv()` will receive everything that you `send()` in a single go.

There is no guarantee that `send()` will even accept everything that you give it.  It will copy whatever it can into the socket's outbound buffer and return the actual number of bytes copied.  So it can accept fewer bytes than requested.

Likewise, `recv()` will copy whatever data is currently available in the socket's inbound buffer, *at least* 1 byte but not *more than* the specified number of bytes, into your specified buffer and will return the actual number of bytes copied.  So it can receive fewer bytes than requested.

You also need to know how much file data is actually being transmitted so you know when to stop reading the data.  Since `recv()` can return fewer bytes than requested, you cannot rely on buffer sizes alone to indicate EOF.

You are not taking any of this into account in your code.

Try something more like this instead:

Server:

```
bool readRaw(SOCKET sock, void *buf, int bufSize)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (bufSize > 0)
    {
        int bytesReceived = recv(sock, pbuf, bufSize, 0);
        if (bytesReceived < 0)
        {
            printf("[!] recv() error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return false;
        }
        else if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            puts("[!] client disconnected");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            pBuf += bytesReceived;
            bufSize -= bytesReceived;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

...

unsigned __int64 fileSize = 0;
if (readRaw(sock, &fileSize, sizeof(fileSize)))
{
    while (fileSize > 0)
    {
        int bufSize = min(fileSize, MAX_BUFF_RECV);

        if (!readRaw(sock, r_buf, bufSize))
            break;

        if (!WriteFile(out, r_buf, bufSize, &n, NULL))
        {
            printf("[!] WriteFile() error %d\n", GetLastError());
            break;
        }

        fileSize -= bufSize;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
bool sendRaw(SOCKET sock, void *buf, int bufSize)
{
    char *pbuf = (char*) buf;
    while (bufSize > 0)
    {
        int bytesSent = send(sock, pbuf, bufSize, 0);
        if (bytesSent < 0)
        {
            printf("[!] send() error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            pBuf += bytesSent;
            bufSize -= bytesSent;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

...

fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
long int pos = ftell(f);
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

if (pos == -1)
    printf("[!] ftell() error\n");
else
{
    unsigned __int64 fileSize = pos;
    if (sendRaw(s, &fileSize, sizeof(fileSize)))
    {
        while (fileSize > 0)
        {
            int bufSize = min(FILE_DOWNLOAD_SIZE, fileSize);

            nread = fread(buff, 1, bufSize, f);
            if (nread == 0)
            {
                printf("[!] fread() error\n");
                break;
            }

            if (!sendRaw(s, buff, nread))
                break;

            uifileSize -= nread;
        }
    }
}
```